# nginx pass php request to a php-apache server , but download instead of executing the php files

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I set up 2 servers , A server is nginx, port 80 . B server is php with apache , port 80 .  If I access B:80/index.php , it works properly .

On server A , the nginx conf :

```
location ~ .*\.php$ {
#fastcgi_pass   B:80;
#     fastcgi_index index.php;
#     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 #     include fastcgi_params;
           proxy_pass http://B:80;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
```

Yes , I know fastcgi , but I just want to try this way , and when I access A:80/index.php , it downloads the php file instead of executing it , whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved , comment this line in nginx.conf

```
 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```